# Whats the name of this UI element

Tags: android, notifications, material-design

What is the name of the grey, oval notice that is present in the attached screenshot, I'd be willing to bet this is a duplicate but I have not way of checking because I do not know what the design element is called

[image: design element]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toast. Here is the official doc:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

To create a toast:

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Text To Show", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```